# Specific fields only via Laravel Collection?

Tags: php, laravel

How do I use Laravel collection to return Specific fields only.

For example:

```
$stores = $this->stores->allStores();
```

This will will return many stores with id, name, description, street, town.

I only need `id`, `name`

Do I need to use `map` or `filter` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pluck()` method:

```
$stores->pluck('id', 'name');
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you update your answer if I wanted to do it by `map` or `filter` how can that be done?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back you shouldn't use `map` or `filter` for that, cuase they are used in another kind of situations. Keep it simple, `pluck()` is made exactly for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel's [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck) method to fetch specific fields like this:

```
$stores = $this->stores->allStores()->pluck('id', 'name');
// Or if - To get an array in result
$stores_arr = $this->stores->allStores()->pluck('id', 'name')->toArray();
```

Hope this helps.